# sysctl: setting key "kernel.softlockup_panic": Invalid argument

Tags: linux, unix, sysctl

When I am trying to set kernel.softlockup_panic value to 30 instead of 0. I am getting Invalid argument error

```
# sysctl -w kernel.softlockup_panic=30
```

Error message

```
# sysctl: setting key "kernel.softlockup_panic": Invalid argument

kernel.softlockup_panic = 30
```

Can anyone please guide?
I am using SLES12 64bit OS

```
# uname -a
Linux linux-r1qg 3.12.28-4-default #1 SMP Thu Sep 25 17:02:34 UTC 2014 (9879bd4) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: This sysctl can be set to either 1 or 0, which should not be surprising. What is the deal with the number 30?

Comment: This is softlockup_panic timer value being set to 30 seconds instead of 0 seconds. It is not necessary all sysctl values are either 0 or 1.

Comment: This is not a timer. This only tells the kernel whether to panic on softlockup. http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sysctl.c#L882

Comment: OK Thank you for the info!

Answer (score 0):

I Have used syctl for other purposes. Guess this params is not supported by kernel . 
 you can check this thru either of the commands

```
sudo sysctl -a  | grep softlockup
 cat /proc/sys /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Comment: Yes, I have already used this commands, softlockup panic is available. first command output: linux-r1qg:~ # sudo sysctl -a  | grep softlockup
*kernel.softlockup_panic = 0*

Comment: Taking a long shot. 

Check out  (this is for ubuntu)
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1789826

as per   https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/lockup-watchdogs.txt  watchdog timer is required for this feature. 

Can you check if watchdog  process is running or /dev/watchdog is created ?

Comment: Thank you for the response!    Yes, I do have /dev/watchdog created.